# Was there any fight between Bheeshma and Lord Hanuman being mentioned anywhere in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, hanuman, bhishma

I recently talked to one of my friends who was telling me the story from Mahabharata(that he has read from an old book) where there was a fight between Lord Hanuman and Bheeshma in the Kurukshetra battle. Lord Hanuman was protecting Arjun from Bheeshma's arrows. Here, Bheeshma had an upper hand over Lord Hanuman as Lord Hanuman was throwing stones at Bheeshma but Bheeshma destroyed them with his arrows. Then Lord Hanuman went out of Kurukshetra to get more stones and in the meantime fight between Arjun and Bheeshma continued.

I wanted to know whether this story is there is Mahabharata or is just a folklore. And if it is there then did Lord Hanuman continued his fight with Bheeshma later on and what was the result?

Answer (score 7):

The most known instance of lord Hanuman meeting any of the Mahabharata warriors, was with Bhima, during PAndava-s 13 years of exile. It's noted in Vana Parva, as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26636/1049).

Though there was lord Hanuman's presence on the flag of Arjuna's cart, there is no single instance of Bhishma and real lord Hanuman meeting face to face.

Besides, I haven't heard this even as a folklore.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one mentioning about Lord Hanuman is mahabharata and that is during pandavas 13 years of exile. During this event Bhima unintetionally stumbled upon lord Hanuman and that is when pandavas gained his blessings and at that time he said bhima that "My blessings protect you all in the war although I will not fight against any kauravas".

So,from this i can say that there is no event about fight between Bheeshma and Lord Hanuman

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a story would even exist, as Bhishma and Hanuman are both wise beyond their ages, and among the wisest beings on earth. They were not brash and were perhaps aware of each others identity at the spiritual level (these are only speculations). Plus Bhishma had promised to not kill any Pandava brothers, and kept his word which was as strong as an elephant's tusk. At most he'd just injure them, that's it.

The only references I know of Hanuman are that he met Bhima, and one perhaps that he had a small fight with Arjuna over the bridge of stones and arrows. Still I don't know about the latter if its true. But Bhishma vs Hanuman, to me sounds impossible. 2 staunch devotees of the Lord, wise enough to understand that, would never fight among themselves over material issues.